# How to get unique random int?

Tags: java, android, random, unique

```
static int n = -1;  
private static int repeatBuffer[] = new int[10];
static {
    repeatBuffer[0] = 0;
    //and more
    repeatBuffer[9] = 9;
}
static public void randomize() {

    do {
        Random r = new Random();
        randomNumber = r.nextInt(20);
    } while (!uniqueInt(randomNumber));
    Log.e(TAG, "" + randomNumber); //here I need have a unique int
}

private static Boolean uniqueInt(int random) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (random == repeatBuffer[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (++n > 9)
        n = 0;
    repeatBuffer[n] = random;
    return true;
}
```

Sometimes I'm getting same int twice, I'm wondering where is the problem? And is it even work? I spend quite a lot of time on this, and I give up. I think I need some minor tweaks in code :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easier way to get a random int is to create a List of integers `List<Integer>`, adding it with numbers that you would like to have. Then shuffling the List using `Collections.shuffle(list);`. Now start reading from the beginning of the list and you will get a unique random int each time.

Just make sure that each time you "read" a number from the list, either remove it from the list or increase the index for where you read.

Comment: Thank you, I have never using that before. I was always using Random r = new Random(); :) List and collections are way more friendly and easier. :)

Answer (score 3):

That's the normal behavior of a random number generator, it's correct to generate repeated numbers as long as the number distribution remains uniform.

If you need a set of unique random numbers, you can generate them inside a loop and ask at every iteration if the newly generated number is present in the set of generated numbers. If not, add it, if yes, keep iterating - until the set has the desired size.

Comment: I think that's what the OP is actually trying to do.  They've just messed up the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Er, a unique random between 1 and 20? What happens when it runs the 21st time?

Try making a `List` of the Integers between 1 and 20. Use `Collections.shuffle()` to shuffle the list. Then pop the first item off the front of the list and use that.